# MYSQL | ENCODE() outputs blob instead of text

Tags: mysql, text, encoding, utf-8, blob

Im trying to encode a simple string by the ENCODE()-function. Using a string it gives me text as output. But using a field it gives me BLOB. How can I get around BLOB and output text for encoded fields?

**Here's what happens:**

`SELECT ENCODE('myText,'myPw')`
 - **Output**: baddade4b04e // *Goal = This + using fieldname*

`SELECT ENCODE(Field,'myPw') FROM myTable`
 - **Output**: [BLOB - 14B]

---

**What I've tried:**

`SELECT CAST(ENCODE(Field,'myPw') AS CHAR(1000) CHARACTER SET utf8) FROM myTable`
- **Output**: Empty rows!

`SELECT CONVERT(ENCODE(Field,'myPw') USING utf8) FROM myTable`
 - **Output**: %  (Output is 1-2 chars, cant be right)

Imagine I have a column `user`. Now I want "PaulPeter" being encoded the same regardless of whether Im encoding the string "PaulPeter" or the field `user` where the value is "PaulPeter".

Could anyone explain this to me? Thanks very much!

**Encrypted string:**

[image: Encrypted string]

**Encrypted field:**

[image: Encrypted field]

*MySQL-Client-Version: 5.5.41*
`user`: *text   utf8_bin*

---

**EDIT:**

I got another question according decoding here: [Click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31850178/mysql-aes-encrypt-decrypt/31850316#31850316)
After being able to encode, I got the same problem there with AES_Encryption. When I encrypt a string I get the output as a string. When encrypting a field with a string-value I get blob. :( Totally annoying.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Both give me BLOBs. MySQL 5.1.something.

Comment: Maybe thats the problem? Im on 5.5.41 here. Added it to my question. Anyway thanks for trying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your user column is of type TEXT. Try casting just that column to CHAR:

```
SELECT AES_ENCRYPT(CAST(Field AS CHAR(1000)),'myPw') FROM myTable
```

Comment: The idea was the right one. Accept my edit so we can close this one. :) Thanks a lot!

Comment: No the Edit, the original code. I will remove my comment above to avoid confusion.

Comment: Ah alright. I was just about hanging myself to get rid of version-differences hah. Thanks again.