# MYSQL | AES encrypt() / decrypt()

Tags: mysql, encryption, cryptography, aes

I need to encrypt a string in a decryptable way. Best way would be by a given password to get a little bit of protection in. Security isnt that important in here.

I picked out AES_ENCRYPT() so far but cant decrypt it.

**Encrypt:** `SELECT AES_ENCRYPT('test', 'test')`
**Output :** `87bd903885943be48a4e68ab63b0ec6a`

**Decrypt:** `SELECT AES_DECRYPT('87bd903885943be48a4e68ab63b0ec6a', 'test')`
**Output :** `NULL` !

Simple question: Why the hell can't I decrypt it? Couldnt find anything about it online.

If the solutions becomes too big (I like it simple) I would also be fine with another method of encryption.

Thanks a lot!

---

*MySQL-Client-Version: 5.5.41*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert the hexadecimal string into binary data first:

```
SELECT AES_DECRYPT(UNHEX('87bd903885943be48a4e68ab63b0ec6a'), 'test') FROM DUAL;
```

Actually, I'm surprised your original `SELECT` statement returned a hex string in the first place. This is what I get:

```
mysql> SELECT AES_ENCRYPT('test','test') FROM DUAL;
+----------------------------+
| AES_ENCRYPT('test','test') |
+----------------------------+
| ???8??;?Nh?c??j                     |
+----------------------------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)
```

I can only get a hex string if I call `HEX()` explicitly:

```
mysql> SELECT HEX(AES_ENCRYPT('test','test')) FROM DUAL;
+----------------------------------+
| HEX(AES_ENCRYPT('test','test'))  |
+----------------------------------+
| 87BD903885943BE48A4E68AB63B0EC6A |
+----------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

(This is in MySQL version 5.6.22)

Comment: Oh god. I've seen this unhex part a lot of times but havnt got onto where to use it. Thanks a lot, works perfectly! (Accepting in 5min).

Comment: Maybe its because of the different mysql-versions? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31847954/mysql-encode-outputs-blob-instead-of-text Here a guy got BLOB where I got Text. (Also different versions).

Comment: If you dont mind, check out my other problem with encryptions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31847954/mysql-encode-outputs-blob-instead-of-text

Answer (score 2):

In MySql Workbench there is a setting under Edit/Preferences/Sql Editor/Sql Execution, checkbox the
`[X] Treat BINARY/VARBINARY as nonbinary character string`

Then a Workbench restart.

```
SELECT HEX(AES_ENCRYPT('secret message','myKey')) into @a FROM DUAL;
select @a; -- 'F5CF7120FF800ECEB4663785EFC19340'

SELECT AES_DECRYPT(UNHEX('F5CF7120FF800ECEB4663785EFC19340'), 'myKey') FROM DUAL;
-- secret message  (shows it fine)

SELECT AES_DECRYPT(unhex(@a), 'wrongKey') from dual;
-- NULL  (at least it is a tip-off that it failed)
SELECT AES_DECRYPT(unhex(@a), 'myKey') from dual;
-- BLOB
```

Now right click on BLOB, "Open Value in Viewer", go between Binary and Text tabs, see "secret message"

Kind of a pain, even despite what I mentioned at top of this Answer, but oh well. It works fine of course in mysql client as opposed to Workbench.

Just thought I would share that, feel your pain on your **other** question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31847954/mysql-encode-outputs-blob-instead-of-text). Sort of client/version specific.

Comment: Oh thanks for noticing. Ill check this out for sure. According my other one: Was simpler than I thought. Was just answered. :)